# Azure static web app environment variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, gatsby, contentful, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to publish Gatsbyjs by Azure Static web app.
I have a plugin (gatsby-source-contentful).

I need to pass variables like:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
},
```

Error:

```
Running 'npm run build'...


> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build /github/workspace
> gatsby build

success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.021s
error Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-contentful":

- "accessToken" is required
- "spaceId" is required
not finished load plugins - 0.905s
```

Where can I pass this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

For Azure Static Web Apps there is two ways to set environment variables one for front-end and one for back-end scenarios.

Since you are using Gatsby, I guess its safe to assume you are building your front-end. For that you will need to add the environment variables on your build configuration (azure-static-web-apps-.yml).

Like so:

```
env: # Add environment variables here
  CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID: <your-id>
```

Here is the link for that in [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#environment-variables).

Not to be confused with this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings) which is used for defining backend environment variables.

Comment: its not safe to publish sensitive environment variables though

Comment: Absolutely, that is why you define your secrets first in Azure and so you it can supply it to your application on build time.

Comment: Hi drinesteban. How can I get the value of the variable defined in Azure in Gatabyjs

Answer (score 1):

They are called [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/). They are intended to store sensitive data such as tokens, identifiers, etc, and they shouldn't be pushed in your repository, so you should ignore them (in your `.gitignore` file).

By default, Gatsby creates 2 environments without noticing you, one for each compilation method:

- `gatsby develop`: uses `.env.development`
- `gatsby build`: uses `.env.production`

*Note: you can change this behavior if needed to add your own environments using `NODE_ENV` custom commands.*

So, to pass your data to your `gatsby-config.js` you just need to create two files (`.env.development` and `.env.production`) at the root of your project. Then, add the following snippet at the top of your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

*Note: `dotenv` is already a dependency of Gatsby so you don't need to install it again*

This will tell Gatsby where to take the environment variables.

You just remain to populate both environment files. Look for the credentials in Contentful and add them in the files using the sane naming than you've set in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID=123456789 
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=123456789
```

Keep also in mind that when dealing with Azure, Netlify, AWS, or similar CI/CD tools, you'll need to provide to the server the same environment files to avoid a code-breaking when pushing the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.
We have no problem in the local environment.
The inquiry is how to provide the Azure server with these variables.

Comment: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2018/11/16/terraform-jamstack-azure-gatsby-azure-pipelines-git/