# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Cannot find module 'dotenv'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

Azure Static Web App (SWA) with integrated API whose **index.js** has

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './environment/misc.env'});
```

Local-run `Azure Static Web Apps emulator` perfect. Merged into GitHub `master` branch triggers Azure CI/CD deploy into Azure, test got

> Stack: Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'

`dotenv` is in SWA's root `package.json`

```
"dependencies":
{
  ...
  "dotenv": "^16.0.0"
}
```

GitHub project, Actions all jobs are good

Comment: Are these helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307614/azure-static-web-app-nodejs-env-variables, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407393/while-running-the-script-throws-cannot-find-module-dotenv, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749078/azure-static-web-app-environment-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWA environment settings
Front-end

- Local, \src\app\environments\environment.ts (or your own customized location)
- PROD AZ cloud, [.yml file, add env](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#environment-variables)

[Backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings)

- Local, api/local.settings.json
- PROD AZ, Portal, Configuration